# Having problems with align*

Tags: equations, align, flalign

This is producing really ugly output

```
\begin{align*}
    \label{fourth term 0}
    \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\Bigg|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}\big(t_j,X(t_j)\big)(t_{j+1} - t_j)\big(X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)\big)\Bigg|\\
    &\leq \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\Bigg|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}\big(t_j,X(t_j)\big)(t_{j+1} - t_j)\big(X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)\big)\Bigg|\\
    &\leq \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\max_{0 \leq k \leq n-1}|X(t_{k+1}-X(t_k)|\cdot \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|f_{tx}\big(t_j,W(t_j)\big)|(t_{j+1}-t_j)\\
    = 0.\int_{0}^{T}\big|f_{tx}\big(t,W(t)\big)\big|dt = 0.\numberthis
\end{align*}
```

I want the output to appear like this (Never mind the $W(t)$ instead of $X(t)$)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Instead of a single `align*` environment, I'd use a nested `equation`/`aligned` combination. That way, you don't have to remember to the desired single equation number.
- Place `&` alignment markers at the beginning of each line, and shift lines 2 through 4 to the right via `\quad` (or `\qquad`) directives.
- The code you currently have for row 2, which features a single pair of `\Bigg`-sized absolute value bars, doesn't correspond to desired output suggested in the screenshot.
- I would exchange the order of terms in rows 3 and 4 to make them line up more easily with the material in rows 1 and 2.
- I recommend you load the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro to create an `\abs` directive. That way, you can concentrate your coding on the *meaning * of the terms instead of on low-level symbol sizing.

A general comment: Your code doens't indicate that `n` (the number of terms in the sums) should be (must be?) a function of `\Delta t` (or, if you prefer, the number of partitions). Without such an indication, the result is trivial as there's a fixed, finite number of terms in the summation even as `\Delta t\to0`. Does the text that accompanies the equations explain that `n` is a suitably chosen function of `\Delta t`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}  % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{fourth term 0}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \, \abs[\bigg]{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}
   \bigl(t_j,X(t_j)\bigr)(t_{j+1} - t_j)\bigl(X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)\bigr) } \\
&\quad\leq \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 
   \abs[\big]{f_{tx}(t_j,X(t_j))} (t_{j+1} - t_j) \cdot
   \abs[\big]{X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)} \\
&\quad\leq
   \biggl[ \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \, 
   \abs[\big]{f_{tx}(t_j,X(t_j)) } 
   (t_{j+1}-t_j) \biggr]
   \cdot \lim_{\Delta t \to 0\,} \max_{\,0 \leq k \leq n-1} 
   \abs[\big]{X(t_{k+1}-X(t_k)} \\
&\quad= \int_{0}^{T}\abs[\big]{ f_{tx}(t,X(t)) }\,dt \cdot 0 = 0\,.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: $\Delta t$ is the length of the longest sub-interval . It is the maximum step-size of the partition.

Comment: @Rhombus - My final comment was *not* about the meaning of `\Delta t`. (I'm an econometrician myself, so I know quite a bit about asymptotic theory...) My point was that unless it's understood that `n=n(\Delta t)=T/(\Delta t)`, say, s.t. `n\to\infty` as `\Delta t\to0`, then the final result, *viz.*, `0`, is absolutely trivial since the first multiplicative term doesn't converge to an integral but, instead, to `0` as well. As it stands, your equations create the impression that `n` is a constant and therefore that it does *not* diverge to infinity as limits are taken.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you want the original ontext, this is basically a step in the proof of Ito-Doeblin formula for an Ito process.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating the first pointer in your answer?

Comment: @Rhombus - With a multirow `align*` environment, it's up to you to issue instructions such as `\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}` (presumably in the final row, right?) and place the `\label` instruction *after* `\refstepcounter{equation}`. In contrast, the nested `equation`/`aligned[b]` setup shown in my answer relieves you of this tedium. All you have to do is issue a `\label` directive -- which you have to do anyway if you wish to cross-referencre the group of equations.

Comment: @Mico: is that the only reason to prefer one over the other? That is, if multiline equations are usually unnumbered, then `align*` is fine?

Comment: @MartinArgerami - I believe that one of the great virtues of LaTeX is it's ability to let writers concentrate on the *meaning* of what they're doing, and not just on the actual contents. It does so by providing several layers of abstraction between the high level at which you're writing your document and the low level at which the typesetting actually takes place. Sure, the *outputs* of the `align*` and `equation`/`aligned` solutions may look the same. The latter solution, though, immediately makes clear what the *intent* is. This'll greatly simplify any future debugging efforts, won't it?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want all columns aligned to the left, hence two additional `&`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \label{fourth term 0}
 &   \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\Bigg|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}\big(t_j,X(t_j)\big)(t_{j+1} - t_j)\big(X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)\big)\Bigg|\\
    &\leq \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\Bigg|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}\big(t_j,X(t_j)\big)(t_{j+1} - t_j)\big(X(t_{j+1})-X(t_j)\big)\Bigg|\\
    &\leq \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\max_{0 \leq k \leq n-1}|X(t_{k+1}-X(t_k)|\cdot \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|f_{tx}\big(t_j,W(t_j)\big)|(t_{j+1}-t_j)\\
  &  = 0.\int_{0}^{T}\big|f_{tx}\big(t,W(t)\big)\big|dt = 0.%\numberthis
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: It is much better to use, say `\bigl( ... \bigr)` instead of `\big( ... \big)`, even if you do not notice the difference. Instead of       `&  = 0.\int_{0}^{T}` there should be       `& = 0\cdot\int_{0}^{T}`.

Comment: +1. I would comment out the `\label` instruction, though, as we're dealing with an unnumbered group of equations.

Comment: @Mico I would also indent lines 2--4 by `\quad` or `\qquad`, but it might be too much for the beginner on our page. :-)